# How to detect tap on react-native-dropdownalert?

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-dropdownalert for my react native app. If a notification comes, the dropdownalert will be shown. How can I detect the tap on the bar?

I saw the [official documentation](https://github.com/testshallpass/react-native-dropdownalert) and there is an onClose method. onClose doesn't meet the need above.

Any method I should use or any good react native 3rd party library I can use instead?

Answer (score 1):

### version>=4.1.0

`onTap` prop added in 4.1.0 release.

```
onTap={() => console.log('User tapped!')}
```

---

### version<4.1.0

`onClose` returns data.

> data = {type, title, message, action}

action is what you need.

action can be `automatic`, `programmatic`, `tap` or `pan`

```
onClose={({ type, title, message, action }) => action === 'tap' && console.log('User tapped!')}
```